# What are the names of these 2 connectors?

Tags: connector

These two types of connectors I do not know the name and I would like to.

1.
[image]

2.[image]

Comment: Those look like Molex barrier strips and in-line crimp connectors.  http://www.molex.com/molex/home

Comment: Look up Euroblock.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. PCB mount screw connectors (ideally, use crimped ferrules on the wire ends with these).
2. Bullet connectors.

Comment: Thanks for the first one but the second one, I can't find anything that looks like the one in the picture I took.

Comment: Is there any indication of the manufacturer on the shrouds of the bullet connectors?

Answer (score 0):

The connector you are looking at might be the MSTB connector made by Phoenix.
The header male header is mounted on the pcb. The plug is a screw type connector. You find these systems in industrial machines where easy replacement of a pcb is important. At the same time the connector remains insulated even when unplugged reducing problems.